# Install postgres extension into Bitnami container as superuser on initial startup

Tags: postgresql, docker, bitnami

I am using the Bitnami Postgres Docker container and noticed that my ORM which uses UUIDs requires the uuid-ossp extension to be available. After some trial and error I noticed that I had to manually install it using the postgres superuser since my custom non-root user created via the `POSTGRESQL_USERNAME` environment variable is not allowed to execute `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";`.

I'd like to know what a script inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` might look like that can execute this command into the specific database, to be more precise to automate the following steps I had to perform manually:

```
psql -U postgres // this requires interactive password input
\c target_database
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Mounting a volume

If you want to do it on startup you need to add a file to the startup scripts. Check out the `config` section of their image documentation: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql

It says in the documentation that you'll need to mount a volume on startup which it sounds like you may know. You can create a simple file called `add-uuid.sql` with the following contents.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

Then you can start the container

```bash
sudo docker run --rm -d \
    --name postgresql \
    -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password123 \
    -v ${PWD}/add-uuid.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/add-uuid.sql \
    bitnami/postgresql:15.2.0
```

The volume line is the important one above. Once it's running you can log in and check that the extension was added.

```
docker exec -it postgresql psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (15.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT oid, extname, extversion FROM pg_extension;
  oid  |  extname  | extversion 
-------+-----------+------------
 13540 | plpgsql   | 1.0
 16384 | uuid-ossp | 1.1
```

---

#### Building own container

If you want to build your own container from scratch for some reason,
Bitnami has most if not all their containers available on GitHub. https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/postgresql. Check the version of postgresql you would like open the Dockerfile and then copy the contents and make any modifications you would like.  This is likely unnecessary.

You can probably add a RUN line or COPY a file into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

---

#### Kubernetes

If working with Kubernetes and deploying via Helm

You can add your scripts in the `postgresql.initdbScripts` variable. [values.yaml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/postgresql-ha/values.yaml#L535).

If the deployment is already running, you'll need to connect as the `repmgr` user not the Postgres user you created. That's default NOT a superuser for security purposes. This way most of your connections are not privileged.

For example I deployed bitnami/postgresql-ha via helm to a k8s cluster in a namespace called "data" with the release name "prod-pg". I can connect to the database with a privileged user by running

```
export REPMGR_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace data prod-pg-postgresql-ha-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.repmgr-password}" | base64 --decode)

kubectl run prod-pg-postgresql-ha-client \
    --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' \
    --namespace data \
    --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql-repmgr:14 \
    --env="PGPASSWORD=$REPMGR_PASSWORD"  \
    --command -- psql -h prod-pg-postgresql-ha-postgresql -p 5432 -U repmgr -d repmgr
```

This drops me into an interactive terminal

```bash
$ ./connect-db.sh 
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

repmgr=#
```

Comment: The OP does not speak of `postgresql-repmgr`, but of [https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql]. And he knows of the startup scripts, but he (and I) needs to know, how to build them to add an extension (without an interactive terminal)

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I apologize the answer was not clear. I have added information above. You do not have to build the container from scratch but mount a file. Mounting a simple SQL file which adds the extension will work. Bitnami builds their containers with contrib so you just have to add them.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but your answer is not getting the point of the OP: He is setting a `POSTGRESQL_USERNAME`. If you do the same, you will notice, that `add-uuid.sql` is executed with that user (which is not a superuser) and installing the extension will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this should work

```
PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -U postgres // this requires interactive password input
\c target_database
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: Your code is missing a line break. And this will only work, if one sets the `POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD` env variable, which is not set for security reasons